# How do I fix "Missing ; before statement" in a if statement with text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Every time I use text in an if statement it says "Missing ; before statement." My code is

```
function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Class');
var class = sheet.getRange('Traits!L3').getValue();
  if (class == 'Warlock' ) {
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7')breakApart();
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7')mergeAcross();
  } else {
    if (class == 'Fighter') {
      sheet.getRange('A7:D7')breakApart();
      sheet.getRange('A7:B7')mergeAcross();
    } else {
    }
```

What it does is break and merge cells based on your class (Warlock and Fighter). Traits!L3 is a data validation that lets you choose a class so if you choose warlock, then it merges 4 cells, if not, (unfinished code). How and why does this show up and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: change your variable name from `class` to something else.

Comment: It looks like your problem can be completely solved without Google App Scripts, why can't breakApart mergeAcross just be done with regular formulas do they really need to be scripts?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a `.` before `breakApart()` and `mergeAcross()`

```
function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Class');
var char_class = sheet.getRange('Traits!L3').getValue();
  if (char_class == 'Warlock' ) {
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7').mergeAcross();
  } else {
    if (char_class == 'Fighter') {
      sheet.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
      sheet.getRange('A7:B7').mergeAcross();
    } else {
    }
```

You should use Data->Named Ranges in google sheets and start naming your cell references then you can call them in code or even formulas by that name.

Comment: @HunterLindsey you can always mark as the answer and vote up now or later. Also I recommend not using Google App Scripts and to use built in formulas as much as you can because GAS is slow and unreliable.

Comment: @HunterLindsey Your question is why were you getting a semicolon error and this resolves that issue, as to whether your code works is an entirely different question as I suggested I would ask a new question on how to solve some of your specific problems without GAS because it often is not necessary. Basically from what I see with your code I don't agree with doing it this way (I would just do regular formulas) but that doesn't mean you can't get it working. You should post a link to your sheet otherwise I have no idea what you are even working with.

Comment: I don't find Google Apps Script slow or unreliable.  Personally, I avoid cell functions

Comment: @Cooper onEdit can only run simultaneously twice and then it ignores all other edits, so if you edit too quickly or have too many people editing at once you will not be guaranteed an onEdit execution, also every time you access the spreadsheet to read or write Google specifically says it is slow and you should do it in batches. A cell function is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Yes.  I never use onEdit in any of my projects.  It's a recipe for disaster which most new users use it way too much.  And I never let multiple user edit directly from spreadsheet,  I always force them to work through a webapp or I won't do the project.

Comment: @Cooper webapp is a great idea, maybe you could post an example of a webapp to give people an idea of how they could solve their problems outside of google sheets but with google sheets. Like just a generic thing.

Comment: I have several examples of web apps already on SO. The problem is that most people don’t know enough about JavaScript, html and CSS. Nor do they understand how to use browser developer tools to debug their code so it’s a real challenge to learn that all at one time along with the variances created by Google Apps Script. It’s a big change from Excels VBA Script.